# How to feed the medicine(Verol Drops) to a cat which didnt eat anything from 2 days?

Tags: cats, diet, eating

Recently, 2 days back my cat got sick and stopped eating. It only drinks water. So today i took him to vet and they gave some injections and also wrote multivitamin named Verol as prescription.

As my cat is not at all trying to eat how can i make him eat the food with Verol drops.

Usually we cook chicken with salt and water everyday and fish once every month. The cooked chicken/Fish is then mixed with rice and given to cats.

But he doesnt even eat the food. We even gave him only cooked chicken alone and yet he doesnt eat. What can i do so that he can get those multivitamins and get healthy.

Comment: Related question [How long can a healthy cat go without food?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/how-long-can-a-healthy-cat-go-without-food)

Comment: Related question [How do I help my cat tolerate a bad-tasting liquid medicine?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/how-do-i-help-my-cat-tolerate-a-bad-tasting-liquid-medicine)